# jquery select box will not move!

Tags: jquery, plugins, select

This plugin has been giving me hell! :/ I finally got it to work, but now when I try and position the select box it won't move! Well... I got the box to move but the dropdown menu stays there. It is really annoying!

1000 internetz to someone who can help me:/

[elektrikhost.com](http://elektrikhost.com) is the site, look where the domain search is. When I place the html somewhere else it still stays there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you put that select in a div tag and add some style to this div to locate somewhere?

```
<div id="select-container" style="float:right; margin-right:20px; ..etc">
  <!-- Here your select box code -->
  <div style="width: 42px; float: right;" id="webmenu_msdd" class="dd">  
  ....
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: and i think your problem is that you set the position to absolute! try changing the position to relative. 
<div id="webmenu_msddHolder" style="height: 0px; overflow: hidden; position: relative;" class="ddOutOfVision">.....</div>